# Not seeing a way to upload build on itunesconnect to update version

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I archived, validated, and uploaded through Xcode like I did before. I'm on itunesconnect trying to submit a new version. I clicked "+ Version or Platform" on the left menu. But when I scroll down to "Build" I only see "Submit your builds using Xcode 6 or later, or Application Loader 3.0 or later." I don't see any text link or '+' to select the new build. How am I supposed to select the new build/version?

Comment: So there might have been a CSS issue or something? I logged out and logged in a few times and still nothing. Eventually after refreshing the page 3 times the little '+' button appeared next to "Builds"

Answer (score 0):

Under `Activity` tab in section `All Builds` make sure your build is successfully processed first. It needs some time before it will become available for submission. Some times it could take a little bit longer (half an hour or even more).

Answer (score 0):

The general flow as per [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ReplacingYourAppWithANewVersion.html) is:

1) Creating the Next App Version in iTunes Connect

2) Uploading the New Build

3) Submitting it for review

It's important to create the new version first, so the build ends up with that version. To get on overview of uploaded / processing / processed builds go to https://itunesconnect.apple.com and choose the app. Then under the activity tab > iOS History > All Builds

[image]